# Performing many UIKit operations blocking main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uiview, uikit

when the app is launched, I'm programmatically creating many complex UIViews with transparent background colour, each being a 'screen' in the app (has to be this way since there's animated background underneath). This causes the app to stay on the static launch image for quite long (about 4 seconds).

I would like to create all the UIViews while an animation is shown. I can't create UIViews on background thread. How can I accomplish this?

Attempt 1:

```c
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];


    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        UIView *baseView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 100)];
        [baseView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 180, 80)];
        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [button setTitle:@"button" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //doesn't work
        [baseView addSubview:button];

        dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ //Finished

            [self.view addSubview:baseView];
        });

    });
}
```

The button is added, but the title is never set. It appears after tapped.

Comment: What type of animation is in the background? Movie? How are you programmatically creating the views? drawRect? How many views? Do they overlap?

Comment: No, I there needs to be an animating UIView on the main thread AT THE SAME TIME as many (10+) complex UIViews are being created. The complex views are not meant to be currently visible, only created.

Comment: The UIViews contain other UIViews like UIButton, UIImageView and UILabel. There's lots of them because the views are complete 'screens' for the game app.

Comment: While this isn't the answer to your question... you mention that "The complex views are not meant to be currently visible, only created".  Are you sure you have to create them on app launch and cannot do it at a more convenient time that does not slow down launch?

Comment: Perhaps, but I want to avoid loading a 'screen' just before it's about to be viewed. I can't think of a suitable situation for the loading. Would it be possible to do just one 'screen' per runloop, giving some time to the animation too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for help. Here's the final solution that I tested and works perfectly.

I created a task manager class, FCTaskManager:

```c
//Header File

typedef void (^TaskBlock)(void);
typedef void (^TaskCompletedBlock)(void);

@interface FCTaskManager : NSObject

-(void)performUITask:(TaskBlock)taskBlock completionBlock:(TaskCompletedBlock)taskCompletedBlock;
-(void)performBackgroundTask:(TaskBlock)taskBlock completionBlock:(TaskCompletedBlock)taskCompletedBlock;

@end



//Implementation

#import "FCTaskManager.h"

@implementation FCTaskManager

-(void)performUITask:(TaskBlock)taskBlock completionBlock:(TaskCompletedBlock)taskCompletedBlock {

    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        @autoreleasepool {

            taskBlock();

            dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                taskCompletedBlock();
            });
        }
    });
}

-(void)performBackgroundTask:(TaskBlock)taskBlock completionBlock:(TaskCompletedBlock)taskCompletedBlock {

    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        @autoreleasepool {

            taskBlock();

            dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                taskCompletedBlock();
            });
        }
    });
}

@end
```

Then I can use the task manager like so:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Create taskManager
    taskManager = [[FCTaskManager alloc] init];

    //Create UIViews, etc WITHOUT blocking main queue
    [taskManager performUITask:^{

        button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 300, 300)];
        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [button setTitle:@"Working" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    } completionBlock:^{

        NSLog(@"CREATED BUTTON");

        [self.view addSubview:button];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Looks like a great approach, but didn't you mean to call `-performBackgroundTask: completionBlock:` instead of `-performUITask:completionBlock:`? Also, in this setup, when the completionBlock gets executed, how can you be sure the `button` view has indeed already been created in the background thread? (Sorry if these are stupid questions, but I'm pretty unfamiliar with all this multi-threading business.)

Answer (score 2):

UIViews are not thread safe in normal usage, and all interaction should occur on the main thread. That said, you should be able to, on some background thread (dispatch queue), create the view, modify its parameters, set complex background colors, etc - as long as the view is not connected to anything (and thus receiving events from iOS). Once the view is completely setup and wired, then dispatch a block with it to the main queue and only then add it as a subview to some other view.

What I would do is dispatch all this work to the normal priority queue after having set up my initial video clip. When all the views have been posted back to the main queue (and thus this work is complete), you can stop the video and start interacting with the user.

Comment: So I can actually create views, add subviews to them and all AS long as they are not added to any visible view? That's very interesting.

Comment: @lukas798, a "visible" view is chained to a window (UIWindow) and receives events. No window in the chain means no events.

Comment: I've tried to do this but unsuccessfully. See the updated question.

Comment: Could you please share some sample code that would do this please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look, you almost have it. When you set these attributes, they post a "setNeedsDisplay", which because they are not viewable have no affect. First, just try to do a "setNeedsDisplay" after adding it to the view (that is, do this in the dispatched block AFTER adding it to the view. Secondly, you may need to set the title after adding the control to the view - I vaguely seem to recall having this very same issue on OSX years ago. You can always do the heavy lifing in the background, then finally set the background color/title/etc after adding the control to a view.